# GetLogicalDrives and bit position 23

Tags: c, winapi

As far as I understand, if I would like to check for `X:\` drive, It would be bit 23 if using the `GetLogicalDrives` function; so, I am trying to test that, but it turns to `0` if I set the bitmask to `>>=23`.

This is my code:

```
DWORD drives;

drives = GetLogicalDrives();

drives >>= 23;

if (drives == 0)
{
    wprintf(L"Error: %lu\n", GetLastError());
}
else if (drives & 1)
{
    wprintf(L"Drive is mounted\n");

}       
else
{
    wprintf(L"Drive is not mounted\n");
}
```

Now, if I set `drives`, for example, to `17`, which, I believe, would refers to letter `R`, It will be tested in the first `else` and, if it is not mounted, will go to the second; so it will show `Drive is not mounted`. Same if I set `drives>>=1`, which refers to B, I think.

It will get `0` only from `19` (letter `T`) to `25` (letter `Z`), if they are not mounted.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value before the bit shift?

Comment: A bitmask returned by `GetLogicalDrives` function. I am receiving, according to the debugger: `263020`

Comment: Did you read https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b0822157-3602-4f5f-9e64-13d2bbc8a95d/environmentgetlogicaldrives-not-returning-network-drives-in-windows-10-os?forum=windowscompatibility yet?

Comment: I didn't, but I would like to know if, in fact, there is any related issue with this function in Windows 10.

Comment: Suggestion: Just read and test the workaround explained there

Comment: It's not clear why you consider it an error if the result of the shift is zero. 263020 = 0x4036c, which corresponds to drives C, D, F, G, I J, and S. (Check my math.)

Comment: @RaymondChen, but it should get all the drives, shouldn’t it? If not, how do I check for not mounted drives?

Comment: No. The X drive is not mounted. `GetLogicalDrives` gets all volumes and I can use `& 1` to test if it is mounted. That is what I understand from the doc on MSDN. No idea if I’m wrong.

Comment: `GetLogicalDrives` returns the drive mapping for the current process, which is referenced from the access token's logon session. In a kernel debugger you can inspect the logon session's device map, plus the one from its referenced `GlobalDosDevicesDirectory`. The overall `DriveMap` is the bitwise OR of the two maps. Note that a logical drive isn't necessarily a volume, and volumes may be available without a drive (e.g. GUID names and NTFS mount points). Use `FindFirstVolume` to list the GUID names of mounted volumes. Then `GetVolumePathNamesForVolumeName` to list the mount points of a volume.

Comment: This question makes no sense. If the drive isn't mounted, its corresponding bit in the bitmask will be 0.

Comment: And, as always, you are calling `GetLastError` at the wrong time. It returns a (potentially) meaningless value, and you have destroyed all evidence that would have allowed you to determine, whether it is.

Comment: @IInspectable, @Johathan Potter, I have updated the question to add clarity. As you can see, if I set `17`, which means `R`, it will test and, if it is not mounted, will print the message in the second `else`. It does not work the same way from `19` to `25`, why?

Comment: It works exactly the same for **all** drive letters. If you get different results for some, then that has to do with *your* environment. Which we have no access to. This question isn't answerable.

Comment: I have Windows 10, version 1709, and that’s the only code I have. Can you try it?

Comment: No, we cannot try to run code on your machine. I can't believe I had to write this.

Comment: I was not talking about trying on my machine, but on yours. I mean, I would like to know if you can try the code to see if the problem is my environment, as you said. I’m just trying to fin some help to understand that behavior. If you believe I have something wrong with my code, please let me know.

Comment: Remove the `if (drives ==0) { error }`. As I noted earlier, that test makes no sense. It causes your code to report a false error. That is why it doesn't work for 19 and higher. You have no drives mounted above S, so the result of the shift is zero, to say "no drives above S".

Comment: The code prints a meaningless error message on my machine (`Error: 0`). I'm not sure why you believe this would help you.

Comment: Thanks for answering again, @RaymondChen. Should I check for `==0` before shifting to test fail function result or that is not needed? And, may you post that answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Go ahead and post your own answer and accept it. I don't need the imaginary points. If you want to test the result of the call against zero, do so before shifting (because if you do it after shifting, then you aren't testing the result of the call). But it's not clear what your program can do to recover. You may as well act as if drive X doesn't exist, which is the behavior you get if you remove the test against zero.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation, @RaymondChen, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation:

> **If the function succeeds, the return value is a bitmask representing the currently available disk drives**. Bit position 0 (the least-significant bit) is drive A, bit position 1 is drive B, bit position 2 is drive C, and so on.
>
> **If the function fails, the return value is zero**. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`.

If the function succeeds and the bitmask does not contain any bits for drives after X, the result of the shift will be 0, causing your code to report a false error.  You need to check for 0 *immediately* after `GetLogicalDrives()` returns, before you shift:

```
DWORD drives = GetLogicalDrives();
if (drives == 0)
{
    wprintf(L"Error: %lu\n", GetLastError());
}
else
{
    drives >>= 23;
    if (drives & 1)
        wprintf(L"Drive is mounted\n");
    else
        wprintf(L"Drive is not mounted\n");
}
```

That being said, you don't need to shift the bitmask itself at all:

```
DWORD drives = GetLogicalDrives();
if (drives == 0)
{
    wprintf(L"Error: %lu\n", GetLastError());
}
else
{
    //if (drives & 0x800000)
    if (drives & (1<<23))
        wprintf(L"Drive is mounted\n");
    else
        wprintf(L"Drive is not mounted\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @Remy Lebeau. Little question if you don't mind: would `GetLastError()` report the correct error code or just `0`?

Comment: @SergioCalderon that is answered in the documentation. If the result of the function is 0, `GetLastError()` will return a valid error code (until another Win32 function is called that resets it)

Comment: Thanks again for answering.